# Regex How to match word across different paragraphs

Tags: python, regex

Its been driving me crazy because I think this should be a simple problem :(

Here is the situation, I would like to create a regex that would extract the text right below "This is a sentence". In this case, its "3.43" and "3.42" For example:

```
This is a sentence 1023 hello:
3.43

This is a sentence 245 byebye:

3.42
```

I wrote the regex:

```
y = re.compile(r'This is a sentence.*\n(.*)|\n(.*)').search(mytext).groups()
```

However this gives me the output "None" for both cases in pycharm. The weird thing is, regex101 shows that it is able to capture the text in both cases. See link below.

https://regex101.com/r/mYDALr/2/

Any idea why the output in Pycharm is "None?"

To add on, is there a way to print just "3.42" or "3.43" depending on the case? I am not sure how to do that so I just decided to use .groups(). I am aware that we can print .group(1) or .group(2) but in my case, I would not know whether the first case or the second case will happen so I would not know which to print.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Edited:
Ive used the solutions provided but now the problem is, i would like to search for the regex string in different documents but the extracted text from for example file A and file B are of different encoding? see example below. So the regex works for file A but does not work for file B. When i print a line in file B it outputs the weird string when u print(copied_line).

[image]

Comment: Different line break styles, perhaps. Use `[\r\n]+`. Actually, the pattern is a bit weird: `\n(.*)` matches a line after a newline symbol.

Comment: `This is a sentence.*\n+(.*)` has better matches.

Comment: And `This is a sentence.*(\r\n|\r|\n)+(.*)` to match any kind of carriage return/newline combination. :)

Comment: Your question is not clear (are all those lines which need to be exctracted in this form X.XX), for that simple text you gave, this is regex r'\d\.\d{2}'

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> test = """This is a sentence 1023 hello:
... 3.43
... 
... This is a sentence 245 byebye:
... 
... 3.42"""
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?:This is a sentence.*)\n+(.*)', test)
['3.43', '3.42']
>>> re.findall(r'(?:This is a sentence.*)\s+(.*)', test)
['3.43', '3.42']
```

I'd recommend the `\s` over `\n` for cross-platform line endings support.

Comment: `\s` will also match things after spaces. (If you don't have anything on the lines below.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, however I am actually reading pdf files and extracting text using the library tika. Now the problem is, the regex works for some documents but not for other documents. 

For example, when i want to use the regex r'(?:This is a sentence.*), it works for file a but not for file b. However, when i copy the line "This is a sentence" from file b and paste it in my regex to get a 'new' r'(?: This is a sentence.*), the regex now works for file b but not file a anymore! I think it might have to do with encoding but python 3 already does that for you isnt it?

Comment: Continued: Python 3 already makes all strings in the form utf-8 so encoding shouldnt be a problem right? if i were to purely type in the words r'(?:This is a sentence.*), this regex would work for file a but not for file b

Comment: Python does handle the encoding for you but you should verify that the string is indeed encoded in utf-8 for both files. Just print the encodings for both files. Don't know if you're PDF parser handles it correctly.